# Is it possible to map letters to a cylinder or a sphere in CSS3 or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I saw a picture mapped to a cylinder in CSS3 and I was wondering if this is possible with a text. Even better would be to map the text to a sphere. If it is not possible with pure CSS, Javascript could be an option.

It must run on all major browsers, also those not having the -webkit- stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything is possible if you learn ...

Comment: I don't know of a solution, but I doubt there's a "global" css property. Usually newer CSS stuff requires multiple -moz- -webkit- and -o- properties (that do the same thing but have different syntax), and some JS for IE

Comment: If there is; it would be a very clever hack. SVG may be the only option here.

Comment: Afaik, CSS3 only allows shifting the view plane in 3 dimensions - a sphere is not possible

Comment: As it is not possible with CSS, you might want to have a look at [how to draw 3d sphere?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584854/how-to-draw-3d-sphere)

Comment: @HTML Developer: look at [this draft](http://www.kerststallendag.be)  of a website. I am asked to write labels on the Christmas balls.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments CSS3 only supports rotating and skewing elements, and doesn't have any support for spheres.

Although you can [fake a sphere](http://raphaeljs.com/ball.html) in SVG using something like Raphael.js, i don't think there's any real support for doing 3D stuff using Vector graphics.  You'd have to map/wrap/skew the text yourself using some crazy math, and it still might not even be possible.

I think your only real hope is to use something like three.js to create an actual cube object.  Then you could write your text to a hidden canvas element to get an image of the text, and map  the image onto the cube as a material, [as in this example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_escher.html).

Comment: My both browsers, FF and Chrome under Ubuntu Linux, give as error message: "Your graphics card does not seem to support WebGL. Find out how to get it here."

Comment: I am analysing [this example](http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css-coke-can/) and trying to transpose it to a div with text...

Comment: I suppose you could try to fake a sphere shape using a mask and lighting effect as he does with his Coke can image. http://www.romancortes.com/ficheros/coke-can.png The effect would likely be very subtle though.  He can cheat in his example because it's a cylinder, and he only has to scale the image segments horizontally to get the rounded effect.  I'm not sure how you'd get that same effect going both horizontally and vertically.  You could try to create a series of divs that form a diamond shape, and then mask over the jagged edges.

Comment: You'd also need a whole bunch of copies of the div, so you could scale each one to a slightly different width and height (biggest segments in the center of the sphere), and then line them all up in order the way he does with his numbered divs.

Comment: Chris: Indeed, I was starting to think in the direction of the Coke can and a bunch of div's. But since my customer doesn't insist on this feature, I will probably drop it silently: _Leave well alone_.