# Library for Javascript 3D Image Manipulation

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, webgl, libraries

I am planning to develop a simple script for image manipulation, but stuck on choosing the right library for it.

The script need to import an image and then positioned nicely on other images. For example a text image overlaid on other product image such as shirt, phone case, etc. Yes, this can be done through basic canvas mannipulation.

The main problem is if the other product is a 3D image such as a cup, bottle, ball, or any rounded image object. The script need to be automatically adjust the text image so the edges of the text will looks like it follows the rounded object. Here's an example:

[image]

Here, "change your thinking, change your world" edge looks slanted as it follows the cup.

I've searched it many times, and only comes up with this libraries (maybe because lack of keyword):

- [ThreeJS](http://threejs.org/)
- [SceneJS](http://scenejs.org/)
- [PixiJS](http://www.pixijs.com/)

The question is, are any of this library can do the job? Should it be a 3D image library? Are there any other libraries that's more suited for this task and what's the keyword?

Comment: I would recommends threejs as it is the best fit for your needs.
The others lib are more animations oriented.

Comment: Also this is an opinion based question, which should probably be flagged to avoid spamming.

Comment: At first, I planned to ask this in stackexchange but in the thread ["should there be a place to ask ..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164400/should-there-be-a-place-to-ask-about-programming-libraries-and-technologies), it says that SO also is the place so here we are.

Comment: Seems similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254094/is-it-possible-to-map-letters-to-a-cylinder-or-a-sphere-in-css3-or-javascript

Answer (score 3):

I believe the general keyword you are looking for is text mapping or image mapping to object. Specifically, try searching for "map text to sphere" or "map text to cylinder".

I dont think any of the libs you listed have out of box support for this kind of thing. Those are rendering libraries where they just render the model data you give them. Whereas what you are looking for is libs that can generate the model data for you.

I am not sure if you are aware of this, but you need a 3D model to map text to. A 2D image does not have sufficient information to do this. Of course, you can fake it by perhaps specific the center and radius of an imaginary cylinder/sphere and do some math to manipulate the pixels so that it looks as if it is mapped to them.

Comment: Yes, many of the examples I seen is only about place an image to a sphere  texture or 3D object that created by code not by using another image. Are there any reference or other library that can be used?