# How to make wireframes for 3D html5 shapes

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, 3d

I'm currently learning how to draw shapes in html5 and I am beginning to move into 3D shapes. I know that in order to make shapes like spheres and toruses, you need to first make a cylinder wireframe, and then apply an equation to transform the wireframe cylinder into the desired shape. For example, you would need to start out with a wireframe like this:
[image]

Then you would apply the parametric equations: x = cos(φ) * cos(θ), 
y = cos(φ) * sin(θ), and z = sin(φ) where θ = 2 π u  and φ = π v - π / 2
which would create a sphere such as: 
[image]

The problem is that I'm not really sure how to make the wireframe in the first place. I've seen that in one implementation you can essentially make a cube and then extrude the sides outward to form a sphere, but I'm not sure if that is the optimal way nor even how to implement it. I haven't found much information online for doing this in html5 without using a library like three js or webgl and have only seen outdated posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584854/how-to-draw-a-3d-sphere). What is the process/algorithm that is needed to create one of these shapes.